# Adding/Removing formControls removes errors on another fields in angular reactive forms

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular-formbuilder

I have an issue regarding adding and removing form controls in angular reactive forms.

consilder the following form,

```
 objBasicInformationForm :any = this.objFormBuilder.group({
   .
   .
   .
   newField : ['',[]]
   checkbox : [false,[]],
   dataArray : this.objFormBuilder.array([this.dataArrayForm()])
 });

 dataArrayForm(){
   return this.objFormBuilder.group({
      id : ['',[]],
   });
 }
```

The field `id` in the data array is validated via an API. If the value has an error, an Error is added using `setError` method.

I have a checkbox for dynamically removing and adding the field 'newField'.

The code for adding and removing the field is as follows

```
 whiteBoardCheckHandler(objEvent : any){
    if(objEvent.target.checked){
      this.objBasicInformationForm.removeControl('newField');
    }
    else{
      this.objBasicInformationForm.addControl('newField', this.objFormBuilder.control('', []));
      this.objBasicInformationForm.updateValueAndValidity()
    }
  }
```

The issue comes up with this process when the field `id` in the form array has an error.
Whenever I check/Uncheck the checkbox, the existing error in the field `id` is removed.

Does anyone know the cause of the issue and how to solve this?
Please let me know if you need any further details.

Comment: Have you tried calling `this.objBasicInformationForm.get('dataArray').updateValueAndValidity()` after calling it on the form ?

Comment: @temp_user , do you mean that I need to call the same after adding/removing new control or adding the error to the field?

Comment: Just after `this.objBasicInformationForm.updateValueAndValidity()`, call `this.objBasicInformationForm.get('dataArray').updateValueAndValidity()`

Comment: @temp_user Tried, Not working

Comment: Why you need to remove the control like that?? Couldn't you just hide the input/checkbox with ngIf in the HTML while you have the control.disabled?

Comment: @Osakr Thanks for the information, Currently the fix has been done in the same way by hiding the field and removing the validations. But I would like to find the problem and the solution in the explained scenario.

Comment: @VinceCyriac you don't need to remove the validations, just set it as disabled and the validations wont trigger

Comment: @Osakr Understood, Thank you
Any other solution for the described scenario.

Comment: Can you also attach a stackblitz, with a demo. Both `addControl` and `removeControl` should internally call the `updateValueAndValidity` method, so I'm bit confused, to why you have this issue. 
Also you are saying that you are making some validation, but without the validation being part of the `async` validators I'dont see where are you re-triggering the validation on form changes.

Comment: I am having this same issue. Need to remove no-longer visible fields, but when I do this using removeControl(), it removes the errors on unrelated fields in the form!!!!

Comment: Why validation getting reset on adding or removing the new formControl in a formGroup.